# How does an axial vector field transform under a diffeomorphism?

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, chirality, diffeomorphism-invariance

Does it behave like a normal vector field?

Comment: If the diffeomorphism doesn't invert the chosen orientation of space, the field should behave the same. But I'm not really sure, so I leave this only as a comment.

Comment: I would guess that in a general setting, an axial vector field is a rank one tensor density of weight one. In which case the answer is no, it transforms like a rank one tensor density of weight one.